# Rails - Statement IF for a join table in the controller

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I would like an advice on the "IF" statement about an action "Favorite" which permit to the user to favorite a game.
One association is necessary for one game. One user ID / One Game ID (in the join table).

I got the unicity in the DB with my model GameUser:

```
class GameUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game
    belongs_to :user
    validates_uniqueness_of :game_id, scope: :user_id
end
```

Controller (which is working, just return an error when I got already favorited the game): 
I would like to write correctly the If and I dont really know how

```
 def favorite
            game = Game.find(params[:id])
            if                                            
     # Here is where I struggle,
     #if User haven't got already a match in the DB (Join table User_ID / Game_ID) then :
                current_user.games << game
                flash[:notice] = "#{Game.name} Favorited"
                redirect_to games_url
                else
                flash[:notice] = "#{Game.name} already favorited"
                redirect_to games_url
                end   
        end
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has Game `has_many :game_users`? If so should be enough

```
if game.game_users.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)
```

note that you can do it even without association

```
if GameUser.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, game_id: game.id)
```

Comment: Thats perfect ! Yes I had already the has_many :game_user , it was just an error with the favorite action , when it was already favorited. But Thanks it worked ! i just changed the IF for a Unless on the second statement ;)